# Request for data dump to include more closed question info

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump

Related to [my previous request about userid of closer info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36245/request-for-data-dump-to-contain-userid-of-closers), I'd also like to request for the data dump:

- close reasons for each close vote (currently 11 for SO)
- for duplicate questions, all of the individual duplicate-of question IDs
- for migrated questions, the URL of the new migrated question

I'm thinking about an idea where questions that are most often marked as duplicate-of are highlighted somewhere. Something like some FAQ stats (actual FAQs, not just "how to use the site" info :).

**Update**: I just noticed that the latest data dump doesn't even contain close and reopen vote types (6 and 7) *at all*. I wonder why that is. Obviously that's a necessary first step.

**Update 2**: It turns out that the February data dump contains data for types 6 and 7, but only 1214 close votes. These seem to be the *active* close votes, that automatically expire after five days or whatever. There are three days worth of close activity in the February dump (29 Jan to 31 Jan), and since the January dump was created more than five days after the month rollover, there were none in the dump for that month.

For this request, I'd like to see the close *resolutions* that are stored somewhere after five close votes have been accumulated and the question is in fact closed.

Comment: That page of dupes idea: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36366/please-quiet-the-rabble http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33803/stop-the-noise

Comment: Yup, this request is inspired by ideas like that. Thanks for the links.

Comment: And what about that greater precision on voting times?

Comment: @Rubens Farias: Probably not going to happen, I think I originally suggested a resolution of hours but Jeff chose days. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/omission-of-vote-time-in-data-dump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new PostHistory.xml file now contains all details that are available when a post was closed as well as many more details. Please see [Anatomy of a Data Dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/anatomy-of-a-data-dump) for a description of all the fields.

Comment: Sure, go for it!