# Could there be close statistics visible to each user?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, statistics

I am very curious as to whether my close judgements correspond to those of the larger community. When I'm vote #5, it's clear enough. Not so much so when it's vote #1. I make my vote, I move on, and I never find out.

As part of understanding the community and tuning my personal standards, I'd like to know, either individually or collectively, how often things I vote to close end up closed.

If there's already a way to do this, I've missed it.

Comment: Please vote for http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Answer (score 5):

It would be nice if vote-to-close/re-open actions were recorded under the user > `activity` tab. I'm often curious myself.

I'm trying to weigh adding features to satisfy my curiosity versus the potential *usefulness* of such a feature. In the case of close/re-open situations, it might be helpful to return to the question to support your decision based on how the comments/discussion is going. Then again, you might just be inviting unnecessary noise.

I would tend to err towards transparency and **help users track the activities they perform on the system**.

Comment: Well, one area in which it would be useful is this election thingy going on right now. It would be quite useful to see each candidate's stats on vote-to-close for the various reasons and vote-to-delete (if a 10k user).

Answer (score 3):

Right now you'll have to sort your beans via Google:

> site:stackoverflow.com "closed as [reason] by [your DisplayName]"

Comment: That works for questions that stay closed, but all close activity seems to be lost once it gets reopened. It's not in the timeline view either. (Not sure about the data dump though.)

Comment: And even if it was, it's not cached by engines that respect the robots.txt file. So that's kind of short. @eth

Answer (score 2):

Sure, could be nice. I'd kinda like to see a short history for *all* the votes I cast - close, open, normal Q&A, comments... Just a quick way to refer back to things I've recently looked at but don't care to bookmark.