# How many questions have I voted to close and voted to delete?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, statistics, vote-to-delete

I'm curious about how well I judge worthy questions in comparison to the rest of the community. How can I get a count of how many questions I have voted to close or delete, and how many of those questions have stayed closed/deleted vs. those that have been reversed? Am I an active closer compared to eligible users at large? (Probably, simply because I close at least a few every day and am aware enough to ask the question.)

Questions that have been reopened do not show that they have been closed, unless I try to close it again and I'm informed that I cannot vote to close again. It would appear that a question timeline doesn't display a close event, let alone a re-open event. My understanding is that questions that have been closed and then re-opened are not shown as such in the data dump, either.

Comment: i admit to being curious about the stats myself, but i'm not sure i really want to know.  it's not something that should turn into a contest, which it would if stats were provided.

Comment: re: wonkiness on reopened questions.  i've noticed this too, but it's a separate issue and really needs its own bug report.

Comment: you should know that close and reopen votes which do not reach the threshold "age away" over time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Answer (score 5):

If you accept a partial answer, you can use [The Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) ([tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial)) to query the PostHistory table. It holds many PostHistoryTypes and you are interested in the rows for Close, Reopen, Delete and Undeleted (PostHistoryTypeId resp. 10, 11, 12, 13)

When these events occur the Text column will hold a JSON with the Voters for that specific event. It is worth mentioning that you can't find individual votes  that aged away, or votes that were casted but didn't lead to an actual final state change for the post. On top of that we don't have deleted posts in PostHistory. So the delete events we can report on are for the posts that have been undeleted later on. So the below statistics only show a partial picture. For a complete picture, SE staff should run the query on the internal SEDE. Trust me, it is totally safe to do so, I'm a trained and qualified professional.

Here is the [actual query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1497188?UserId=40468).

```sql
declare @userid int = ##userid:int?40468##

;with close_success as (
select postid
     , creationdate
     , posthistorytypeid
     , voters.id [userid]
from posthistory
cross apply openjson(text,'$.Voters') with (id int '$.Id') voters
where posthistorytypeid = 10
and voters.id = @userid
),
reopened as (
  select ph.postid
       , ph.creationdate
       , ph.posthistorytypeid + 100  [posthistorytypeid] 
       , cs.userid
  from posthistory ph 
  inner join close_success cs on cs.postid = ph.postid 
  where ph.posthistorytypeid = 11
  and ph.creationdate > cs.creationdate
),
reopen_success as (
select postid
     , creationdate
     , posthistorytypeid
     , voters.id [userid]
from posthistory
cross apply openjson(text,'$.Voters') with (id int '$.Id') voters
where posthistorytypeid = 11
and voters.id = @userid
),
closed as (
  select ph.postid
       , ph.creationdate
       , ph.posthistorytypeid + 100  [posthistorytypeid]
       , rs.userid
  from posthistory ph 
  inner join reopen_success rs on rs.postid = ph.postid 
  where ph.posthistorytypeid = 10
  and ph.creationdate > rs.creationdate
),
delete_success as (
select postid
     , creationdate
     , posthistorytypeid
     , voters.id [userid]
from posthistory
cross apply openjson(text,'$.Voters') with (id int '$.Id') voters
where posthistorytypeid = 12
and voters.id = @userid
),
undeleted as (
  select ph.postid
       , ph.creationdate
       , ph.posthistorytypeid
       , ds.userid
  from posthistory ph 
  inner join delete_success ds on ds.postid = ph.postid 
  where ph.posthistorytypeid = 13 
  and ph.creationdate > ds.creationdate
), combined as
(
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from close_success
  union all
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from reopened
  union all
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from reopen_success
  union all
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from closed
  union all
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from delete_success
  union all
  select userid, posthistorytypeid, postid from undeleted
)

select userid
     , [10] [Closed]
     , [111] [Later Reopened] 
     , [11] [Reopen]
     , [110] [Later Reclosed]
     , [12] [Deleted]
     , [13] [Undeleted] 
from combined
pivot (
count(postid) for posthistorytypeid in ([10], [111] , [11], [110], [12] , [13])
) pivotcols
```

When run today this is the result for your Stack Overflow profile:

| userid | Closed | Later Reopened | Reopen | Later Reclosed | Deleted | Undeleted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 40468 | 139 | 42 | 6 | 2 | 15 | 16 |

It might seem strange that there more Undeleted than deleted events. That is due to a beauty like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3094925/timeline). Extending the query to compensate for these kind of outliers would complicate the query significantly without a clear benefit for doing so. In case any one is interested to make that improvement: please give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

> **Questions that have been reopened do not show that they have been closed,** unless I try to close it again and I'm informed that I cannot vote to close again. It would appear that a question timeline doesn't display a close event, let alone a re-open event. My understanding is that questions that have been closed and then re-opened are not shown as such in the data dump, either.

What? The full open and close history is shown in revision history for the question itself.

The timeline view is still experimental and frankly quite buggy. It should not be used as an official reference for, well, anything.

edit: quoted the relevant section I was responding to. The bold sentence is not correct; the question revision history does indeed contain all close and reopen events, along with what users were involved in said events.

Comment: What? He's talking about per-user statistics, not per-question statistics.

Comment: @jon see my edit. I was responding to the second half. This is the problem with "questions" that have multiple sub-questions..

Answer (score 0):

Regarding questions which have been successfully closed by a certain user, you can use [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1162944/how-many-questions-have-i-helped-to-close) SEDE query. Just write the user's `UserId` and you will get successfully closed questions which they voted to close.