# Does the data-dump contain all close votes cast?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, data-dump

Does the data-dump contain all votes cast by people, or only those close votes that are displayed (i.e. votes on posts that got enough votes to close)?

Comment: See here as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37524/request-for-data-dump-to-include-more-closed-question-info

Answer (score 2):

Close votes are not part of the data dump.  Questions that are closed are part of the data dump, with an indicator (the timestamp in the `ClosedDate` column), however that is the only information provided.

To see the table and columns that make up the data dump tables, you can look at the information provided when creating a query on SEDE:  http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new